# How does Facebook app handle layout changes when keyboard appears?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Facebook app is just amazingly handling UI changes at login screen. Check it out.

**No keyboard**

[image]

**With keyboard** (notice how *need help?* and *English Change* views disappear)

[image]

Yes, I do know about the *adjustPan* and *adjustResize* settings, but how does Facebook set exactly which views will be visible when keyboard is present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like they are showing/hiding specific text (such as need help or English in example above), when Soft keyboard becomes visible.

[Now, in Android, there is No direct way to detect if soft keyboard is visible or not.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-platform/FyjybyM0wGA)

Why?

Below is the Answer from Android framework Engineer.

> The IME being shown has little meaning, since exactly how the IME
> behaves is up to it -- it may be a transparent overlay and not impact
> the application, a small strip, or all other kinds of things.
>
> Due to this, the main way you interact with the IME is by setting your
> softInputMode to be resizeable so when the IME says it wants to
> occlude part of the screen your app's UI will get resized to take that
> into account if needed.

But, there are different ways/methods/workarounds by using which Apps (like Facebook) could potentially detect if Soft keyboard is visible or not and based on the outcome, app could show/hide texts/widgets in it's UI.

Method 1:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity()
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    if (imm.isAcceptingText()) {
        //soft keyboard is shown, so hide "need help" text, for example
    } else {
        //Software Keyboard was not shown;
    }
```

Method 2:

```
final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.activityRoot);
activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
        new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                int heightView = activityRootView.getHeight();
                int widthView = activityRootView.getWidth();
                if (1.0 * widthView / heightView > 3) {
                    //Make changes for Keyboard not visible
                } else {
                    //Make changes for keyboard visible
                }
            }
        });
```

Now both Above mentioned methods does not necessarily works 100% in every situations (as one can expect from non-supported operation way out of SDK)

Facebook may be using any of the above method or who knows, they may have implemented it in different way!

Answer (score 0):

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        // view/hide whatever you want depending on the hasFocus value
        // hasFocus == true -> keyboard shown
    }
});
```

Comment: That might be a solution, but what when a user presses the back button and keyboard disappears, what then? EditText still has focus and keyboard is no longer there.

Comment: You can always override the `onBackPressed` and show items again, also make the edittext lose the focus.

Answer (score -2):

```
edittext.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            edittext.requestFocusFromTouch();
            InputMethodManager lManager = (InputMethodManager) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            lManager.showSoftInput(edittext, 0);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is in no way related to my question.